# FMDB - How can I assign query result to variable?

Tags: ios, swift, fmdb

I'm using FMDB module to work with SQLite in my swift project.
Now I can add new records to database. But also I want to show some query results in textField or even in label.

Here's my part of code that I'm trying to use. But it doesn't works.
Please help me

DataBaseModel.swift:

```
func getElectr100() -> String {
    sharedInstance.database?.open()
    let tarElectr100:FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("SELECT tarif_value FROM tarifs WHERE tarif_name = ?", withArgumentsIn: ["electr100"])
    sharedInstance.database!.close()
    let resultItem = String(describing: tarElectr100)
    print(resultItem)
    return resultItem
}
```

ViewController.swift:

```
resultLabel.text = databaseModel.getElectr100(????)
```

What should I write in ViewController.swift to get the value? How to do it correctly?

Comment: I don't get your question. Can you try to rephrase it?

Comment: In 2 words.
I want to query data from database(result will be float number, e.g. "6,47")
And then assign this data to variable with type float or even string.

Comment: Your function doesn't take any arguments so I don't understand why you have ???? in there.  If you take that out I don't see why your function wouldn't work, as long as you it actually returns a string.

Comment: a lot of ???? - this is mean that I can't get what should I write there.

Comment: What about reading the documentation? You'll learn how to use FMResultSet here: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#executing-queries

Comment: There even is a Swift sample code that tells everything you need: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#swift

Comment: Gwendal Roué - thank you for links! I'm starting reading right now. Hope it'll help)

Comment: Yes it will help. Reading documentation is generally an excellent way to answer your questions, and get a better understanding of what you are doing.

Comment: Gwendal Roué - unfortunately I've faced another problem, that is blocking verification if my function works.